# Unable to POST xml string to webservice with PHP

Tags: php, webservices-client

I've been working on this for days and I can't seem to get it to work. Does anyone see a problem with the code below?

The result is nothing. I get no response from the service whatsoever. I've confirmed that the webservice, written in .Net, can accept and xml string, I've matched their schema, etc. But I get no response back.

I should also mention that I'm new to using web services with php but have done this in .Net countless times.

Additionally, is there a way to test the webservice .asmx to view any type of error output in php just to see if it's even working on the server side?

```
<?php
$url = 'https://someurl/someservice.asmx';
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <query>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <login>userName</login>
        <password>password</password>
        <keyword>cancer</keyword>
    </query>'; 

$c = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Content-length: ".strlen($xml))); 
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'xmlInput='.urlencode($xml)); 
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, (int)30);  

$xmlResponse = curl_exec($c); 
curl_close ($c); 
echo 'Output :: '.$xmlResponse;
?>
```

Comment: `SoapClient` http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php works  perfectly fine ... must you use `curl`

Comment: Fivell - "SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding the following to your request?

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

try without

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

or whrite

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>
```

Comment: Do I have to somehow account for https?

Comment: I've removed this element altogether. Still no responses from the web service. What I don't understand is why I get no response unless the web service is throwing an internal error.